# Java keystore safety on the backend

Tags: java, security, tomcat, ssl

Ok, guys. So i made some keys with a JDK's keytool:

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias clientkey -keyalg RSA ....
keytool -genkeypair -alias serverkey -keyalg RSA ....
```

Made some import/export:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias clientkey -file .... 
Certificate stored in file <client-public.cer>

keytool -importcert -keystore server.jks -alias clientcert -file client-public.cer -storepass storepass -noprompt
Certificate was added to keystore

keytool -exportcert -alias serverkey -file server-public.cer -keystore server.jks -storepass storepass
Certificate stored in file <D:\server-public.cer>

keytool -importcert -keystore client.jks -alias servercert -file server-public.cer -storepass storepass -noprompt
Certificate was added to keystore
```

I've got four files: client.jks, server.jks, client-public.cer and server-public.cer.

My Tomcat's config:

```
<Connector 
        clientAuth="true" port="8442" minSpareThreads="5" maxSpareThreads="75"
        enableLookups="true" disableUploadTimeout="true"
        acceptCount="100" maxThreads="200"
        scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
        keystoreFile="server.jks"
        keystorePass="storepass"
        truststoreFile="server.jks"
        truststorePass="storepass"
        SSLVerifyClient="require" SSLEngine="on" SSLVerifyDepth="2" sslProtocol="TLS" 
    />
```

And on the test client:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "server.jks");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "pass");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "client.jks");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "pass");
```

And it works fine. All traffic is encrypted.
My doubts is about this client.jks file. Is it safe to hold it in Android app that should use backend? Can somebody decompile APK, stole file and decrypt requests/response to/from server? Or is it ok now?

Comment: **App should NOT have `server.jks`**; that sometimes allows eavesdropping and definitely allows MitM. if app only has **`client.jks`** and an adversary does get it, they cannot decrypt connections done by legitimate client(s) but they **_can_ make _their own_ connection(s)** and send request(s) and see the response(s) to those request(s) unless you have other app-level authentication on the server that is not in your Q.

Comment: Thanks. Not it's clear for me.